# Spring MVC Class Not Found Exeption jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting error when I try to run Spring MVC code.

FYI - I am using Intellij IDE, Tomcat 9.0.7 Server and Smart Tomcat plugin

created simple hello world project following youtube tutorial

web.xml ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        ">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.mvc"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>
    <bean name="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

HomeController.java ->

```
package com.spring.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String printHellowWorld()
    {
        //modelMap.addAttribute("message", "Hello world and welcome to spring MVC!");
        return  "hello";
    }
}
```

pom.xml dependency ->

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
     <version>6.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Error Message -> Error from tomcat server log

```
29-Apr-2023 22:15:29.131 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/SpringMVC-Bipin] threw load() exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2470)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2470)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2470)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:469)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1020)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:960)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4672)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4973)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:689)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1888)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:582)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1666)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1301)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1283)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: Issue is resolved after downgrading spring MVC version to 5.x.x